# How to spy on an NPM package in Angular

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have an npm package that I'm using in a service. I'm using it by importing the module and setting the value in the constructor.

```
import * as fullscreen from 'screenfull';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class FullscreenService {
    private renderer: Renderer2;
    private _fs;

    constructor() {
        if (fullscreen.isEnabled) {
            this._fs = fullscreen;
            this._fs.on('change', () => {
                if (!this._fs.isFullscreen) {
                    this.isFullScreen = false;
                    this.bodyClass(false);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    open() {
        this._fs.request().then(() => {
            ....
        });
    }
}
```

In my tests, I need to spy on the `fullscreen` properties and return a different value. This specific package has to be mocked because the functions it contains break the testing. I've tried every version of spy I can think of.

```
test.spec.ts

import * as fullscreen from 'screenfull';

const mockScreenfull = {
    isEnabled: true,
    isFullscreen: false,
    request: () => {
        return Promise.resolve(true);
    },
    toggle: () => {
        return Promise.resolve(true);
    },
    exit: () => {
        return Promise.resolve(true);
    },
    on: () => {
        return Promise.resolve(true);
    },
};

describe('Service: Fullscreen', () => {
    let service: FullscreenService;
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [FullscreenService],
        });
        service = TestBed.get(FullscreenService);

        // Methods I've tried that try to return the mock
        spyOn(fullscreen, 'exit');
        spyOnAllFunctions(fullscreen);
        spyOnAllFunctions(fullscreen).and.callThrough();
    });

    it('should ...', inject([FullscreenService], () => {
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    }));
});
```

The problem is I can't figure out how to reference an `npm package` since it is not a provider. If I call fullscreen.request() in my service, the spec will still try running the npm package instead of the mock.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Usually, you do something like `var fullscreen = spyOn(...`